# Null value in angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am using smart-table filter. This works perfectly 3 days ago and all of a sudden this line: `propertyValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTextSplit[y]) !== -1` is giving a **Null** value for the variable ***propertyValue***. My table works perfectly also. And also my stSearch works also if i remove my filter. But I need this filter for strict search.

```
App.filter('filterByObjectName', function ($filter) {
    return function(input, predicate){
        var returnArray = [];
            angular.forEach(predicate, function(value, key){
                var searchTextSplit = value.toLowerCase().split(' ');
                for (var x = 0; x < input.length; x++) {
                    var count = 0;
                    for (var y = 0; y < searchTextSplit.length; y++) {
                        let propertyValue = input[x].ItemName;
                        console.log(propertyValue)
                        console.log(propertyValue.indexOf(searchTextSplit[y]) == -1)
                        if (propertyValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTextSplit[y]) !== -1) {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (count == searchTextSplit.length) {
                        returnArray.push(input[x]);
                    }
                }
            });
        return returnArray;
    }
});
```

Down here is my debug, line 113 are propertyValue results and you can see there that it goes to null.

[image: Debug Image]

Comment: you need to debug and see

Comment: Yes I have, and here it is and i don't get it.

Comment: Can u setup a plunkr or fiddle ?